# UICollectionView drag and drop remove translucent cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, drag-and-drop

I'm using iOS 11 drag and drop API for reordering and want to remove translucent cell which appears on start dragging. Is it possible? For dragging I use only required method of UICollectionViewDragDelegate:

```
- (nonnull NSArray<UIDragItem *> *)collectionView:(nonnull UICollectionView *)collectionView
                     itemsForBeginningDragSession:(nonnull id<UIDragSession>)session
                                      atIndexPath:(nonnull NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSItemProvider *itemProvider = [NSItemProvider new];
    UIDragItem *dragItem = [[UIDragItem alloc] initWithItemProvider:itemProvider];

    return @[dragItem];
}
```

[image]

Comment: can you get cell start dragging method?

Comment: nah. if u want custom behaviour of ios object, then u need customize it

Answer (score 1):

You can customize your cell during the drag/drop lifecycle by overriding `dragStateDidChange(_ dragState: UICollectionViewCell.DragState)`

```
class MyCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    //...
    override func dragStateDidChange(_ dragState: UICollectionViewCell.DragState) {

        switch dragState {
        case .none:
            self.layer.opacity = 1
        case .lifting:
            return
        case .dragging:
            self.layer.opacity = 0

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

On your cell class override this method:

```
override func dragStateDidChange(_ dragState: UICollectionViewCell.DragState) {

    switch dragState {
    case .none:

        self.layer.opacity = 1

    case .lifting:

        return

    case .dragging:

        self.layer.opacity = 0
    }
}
```